# Play Store - Internal app sharing does not work

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I am trying to upload my app using internal app sharing last 2 days, but no matter what I do, I cant make it work. This is what I did:

1. In Console I clicked on app -> release -> internal app sharing
2. I uploaded apk
3. I added myself into email list both UPLOADERS AND TESTERS (1st tab) and also EMAIL LISTS -> Downloaders (2nd tab)
4. I even enabled "Anyone you shared the link with can download"

[Here is how it looks in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZCIr.jpg)

APK was sucessfully uploaded, and then I copied the link and saved it to Google Keep.

Then I try to open the link on my phone, I click on link, it opens [webpage displaying this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6MAb.jpg) and when I click on "OPEN IN PLAY STORE", it just takes me to Play Store, but there is only official version available (not the internal version I uploaded).

Am I doing anything wrong? I try almost 2 days to make a simply thing like this work, and it is very frustrating...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing we can do right now - Internal app sharing seems to be totally broken at the moment. Great work Google

Comment: @Google this is serious issue. It's unacceptable that this is still not fixed. I had tried same thing few years ago too. It shows new version when clicked on a link without install button and when we go to app details it shows production app instead of internally shared one. Please fix otherwise remove this feature. Apple TestFlight works smoothly.

Comment: guys, please check my answer on this page. now (august 2022) its works.

Comment: @ZainalFahrudin I checked your answer. I am talking about internal app sharing only to quickly share a build for testing. But this just does not work.

Comment: @TechHelper is the app have release version on google play? check best practice https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/

Comment: @ZainalFahrudin Yes app has release version on play store. All the things are proper as per the link you have shared. It just installs play store live app instead of newly uploaded test app.

Comment: @TechHelper internal app sharing provide a link to install, not from playstore. did you get it?

Comment: 1 more, makesure to active internal app sharing mode on playstore app. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57478895/5327495

Comment: @ZainalFahrudin That is also done bro.

Comment: @TechHelper is your internal app sharing still not work? i'm interest to help

Answer (score 7):

You need to [turn on the option](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en#zippy=%2Cadd-authorized-uploaders%2Cadd-authorized-testers) to use Internal App Sharing in the Google Play app on your phone.

Look under the heading **How authorized testers turn on internal app sharing**

Before authorized testers can download apps using internal app sharing, they need to turn on internal app sharing on their Google Play Store app.

1. Open the Google Play Store app Google Play.
2. Tap Menu Menu > Settings.
3. In the “About” section, tap the Play Store version 7 times.
4. After the Internal app sharing setting appears, tap the switch to turn on internal app sharing.
5. Tap Turn on.

(Note that in 4. above, the option may appear under the "User Controls" section)

Comment: Yes David, that is correct - but it does not work. First problem is, I could not find an option "Internal app sharing" where it was supposed to be (in About section) but I found it later in "General" section. Quite confusing...Anyway even after I found it and enabled it, even that did not help, because form some reasons, internal app sharing last weeks DOES NOT WORK AT ALL - Google screwed up something and apparently it was reported by many users already, also here: https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ny2kky/play_store_internal_app_sharing_does_not_work/

Comment: Yes 'Internal App Sharing' is under the general section and it is working now. I created an app bundle in the internal test track and included my email in the list of testers and was able to download the app.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something I just noticed. In other words, it might not be applicable to your specific case.

I uploaded my app's aab file to "Internal app sharing". This is something I've done many times in the past, so I expected no surprises. After uploading, I sent the link to my phone and opened it from the phone. Google Play showed up, but it was stuck with the spinning wheel forever. Uploaded the aab file again, and stuck again.

Then I tried previous uploads in "Internal app sharing" one at a time. The one from a few weeks ago worked, but none of the more recent ones did. I'm not entirely sure what happened between a few weeks ago and now, but I couldn't think of anything particular that might be the cause of the problem.

Then I uploaded from a different account that is registered as one of the uploaders. The file uploaded from the secondary account worked. I uploaded the same aab file from my primary account, and now it started to work as well. The links that didn't work before still didn't work.

I'm not sure uploading from a different account has anything to do with it, or perhaps it was just a coincidence, but if you are desperate, you might want give it a try.

Also, removing the tester's email from `Google Play Console -> Internal app sharing -> Uploaders and testers` and then adding it again was occasionally effective in resolving the issue. Might be a good idea to clear Play Store app data as well. Make sure to enable `Play Store -> Settings -> General -> Developer options -> Internal app sharing`.

Answer (score 4):

Just want to share my '*misunderstanding*' about  Internal app sharing.

1. [internal app sharing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internalappsharing/) is different with [internal testing](https://play.google.com/console/about/internal-testing/).
2. both have different menu email listing too.

   internal app sharing on **Setup > Internal app sharing** :
   [image]

   internal testing on **Testing > Internal testing** :
   [image]

In my case, i have setup testers list on internal testing, but not yet in internal app sharing. The link from internal app sharing not work. `After added email list on internal app sharing, the link work and can install from it.`

hope it's help.

Comment: Note the google accounts matching email addresses should have a country assigned at the Google Play Store level, it should match the app distribution countries.  _Settings>General>Account and device preferences>Country and profiles_ then input a valid credit card so Google Play Store assigns you the matching country

Answer (score 3):

In my case all i needed to do is go to
**Testing -> Internal testing**
and scroll down in the testers tab and get **the link** under **"How testers join"**.

Comment: Finally, this method works for me after spending several hours to solve using other solutions. When clicking the "Join on the web" link and you have been invited to an internal test and you should accept the invitation. And another thing is your email should add to the testers list, otherwise, you get a message "App not available for this account". So make sure to add the tester's email even if you think of to "Join on the web" method to join the test.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

I have tried both **Internal Testing** & **Internal App Sharing**, both Tester link doesn't work for me, getting

> 'Can't download the app..Try again and if it still doesn't work, see
> common ways to fix the problem'

Turn on Internal App Sharing in playstore, i have followed the steps in below link [Google Play not updating internal app automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618739/google-play-not-updating-internal-app-automatically/73850281#73850281)

**Alternalte Method to test Application for both watch and phone**

1. Install 'Wear Installer' app on watch & phone.
2. Turn on Developer Options in watch.(Settings->About->build number(press four times)).
3. Turn on Debug over Wifi.(Settings-> Developer Options-> Turn on Debug over Wifi)
4. Link to install from phone - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freepoc.wearinstaller&hl=en_IN&gl=US
5. Open the 'Wear Installer' app on watch, it will show you the IP Address.
6. Open the 'Wear Installer' app from phone and add the watch IP Address.
7. Select the watch apk in the phone in Downloads of 'Wear Installer'.
8. It will start connecting to watch & press 'Allow Debugging from this device' in watch.
9. Watch will be connected with phone.
10. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKtMP.jpg)Click install in 'Wear Installer' in phone.
11. Apk will get installed in watch.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is you open internal app sharing url in google chrome. try to open url with google app with this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox