# How to automatically rollout an app to internal testers?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I’m trying to set up the automatic rollout of new draft app versions from Google Play to all internal testers.

Everything is automated up to the very last step: the issue I am facing is that it requires a manual intervention to "Review and Release" by clicking on the blue arrow here:

[image]

and then clicking on "Start rollout to Internal testing" here:

[image]

Is there a way to automate this last part like in Test Flight, and have the app be automatically updated on all devices? Or at least available for Internal Tester to update directly through Google App store after receiving the email?

Comment: I want to know this too

Comment: This seems useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754125